# Bat script pausing while performing long action

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, sleep

I'm running a bat script on a Windows 2008 server. The script is launching a jar file which is creating indexes in a database. Each index may take several minutes to create and during some of those creations, the command prompt pause. I have to hit enter so the script can continue running. I'm guessing this can be due to index creation being to long, the command prompt go to 'sleep' and it has to be woken up, be I couldn't find any meaningful information about such a behavior.

Is there any way to prevent the command prompt to go to 'sleep' like that?

Here the part of the script lauching the jar :

```
echo [INFO] Starting build SQL Index 4P8...>>%logFile% 
set msg=[INFO] Creating SQL INDEX FILE... 
echo %msg% 
echo %msg%>>%logFile% 

set UserName= 
set PassWord= 
"..\jre\bin\java.exe" -jar %toolFile% -port=%portNumber% -u=%UserName% -p=%PassWord% 

if ERRORLEVEL 1 ( 
        echo [FAILED] Failed to create SQL INDEX FILE, please see Java Logs... 
        echo [FAILED] Failed to update SQL INDEX FILE, please see Java Logs...>>%logFile% 
        exit 1 
) 

set msg=End of the application, please see logs ! 
echo %msg% 
echo %msg%>>%logFile%
```

It's not really relevant though, as the pauses occur during the jar execution.

Comment: is "Quick edit mode" active? Then an accidential click into the cmd window would mark something and the output stops. "Enter" would then copy the marked part to clipboard and the output continues.

Comment: without the script who knows? maybe there is some 'pause' here and there or... post the script (or at least the relevant part).

Comment: I added the script, but the pauses occur during the jar execution. There are no 'pause' in the script. Quick Edit mode is also disabled.